# Resize excel file while downloading in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am creating Excel file download using NOPI libraries. I have lot of data to show in Excel file which taking long time and big file size.

Is there anyway we can reduce Excel file size while downloading? Now file size is 32 MB wants to this size.

Current code:

```
If sqlDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim dtExcel As DataTable = sqlDs.Tables(0)
    For Each column In dtExcel.Columns
        row.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(column.ColumnName)
        'sheet1.AutoSizeColumn(j)
        sheet1.SetColumnWidth(j, 500)
        j = (j + 1)
     Next
     Dim iRow As Integer = 2
     'Double Cell Style
     Dim cellDoubleStyle As HSSFCellStyle = hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle
     cellDoubleStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00")

     'Integer Cell Style
     Dim cellIntStyle As HSSFCellStyle = hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle
     cellIntStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("0")

     'Date Cell Style
     Dim cellDateStyle As HSSFCellStyle = hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle
     cellDateStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat(Format("m/d/yy"))

     For Each dr As DataRow In dtExcel.Rows
         j = 0
         Dim value As Double
         Dim colInt As Integer
         row = sheet1.CreateRow(iRow)
         For Each col As DataColumn In dtExcel.Columns
             If Double.TryParse(dr(col).ToString, value) Then
                Dim cell As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(j)
                If dr(col).ToString.Contains(".") Then
                   cell.SetCellValue(value)
                   cell.CellStyle = cellDoubleStyle
                Else
                   cell.SetCellValue(value)
                   cell.CellStyle = cellIntStyle
                End If                        '
             ElseIf IsDate(dr(col).ToString) Then
                   Dim cell As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(j)
                   Dim dt As New DateTime
                   DateTime.TryParse(dr(col).ToString, dt)
                   cell.SetCellValue(dt)

                   cell.CellStyle = cellDateStyle
             ElseIf Integer.TryParse(dr(col).ToString, colInt) Then
                   Dim cell As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(j)
                   cell.SetCellValue(colInt)
             Else
                   row.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(dr(col).ToString)
                  'sheet1.AutoSizeColumn(j)
             End If
             j = j + 1
          Next
          iRow = iRow + 1
       Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not using xslx format, you might consider packing the file before sending to the response stream. As the size of the excel document relates to the amount of data you store in it, you probably won't be able to reduce it much within the document.

Comment: Do we have any good open source libraries in C# or vb.net to create .xlsx files?